# How can I have the input stay even if it's reloading after the post request?

Tags: flask, python-3.6

So, I've written a script where I've got an input tag inside the form tags.
And I'm using Flask (which is server-side) to get the input and to do some stuff with the input. But I just don't want that the input will go blank after reloading the page. Is there any way to have the input stay?

Comment: Without posting code is is quite hard to help but normally you would look into something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281216/how-can-i-keep-field-values-in-a-form-after-submit

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!